# MS Access TableAdapter Get Identity after insert

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, ms-access, identity

I'm VB .net 2010 with a MS Access 2010 Database.

The wizard created a DataSet with all the tables from the database. So, I can use

```
Me.CostumerAdapter.Insert("New Costumer")
```

And that works flawless.

But then I've a grid with some Products (Just the Name)

```
Product #1
Product #2
Product #3
...
```

When I save the new costumer I need to get its ID so I can insert the products list. Product & Costumer already have a foreing key relationship.

How can I get the Costumer inserted ID? Or how can I save all together?

All I found was for SQL Server (@@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY).

I tried adding a new INSERT Statement on the datatable (dataset):

```
INSERT INTO Costumer VALUES (?); 
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

Set the query to Scalar and that gave me an error. ('Characters were found after query')

Thanks!
Sorry for any grammatical error.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;815629

Comment: Yeah but it uses oledbcommand. I'm looking for a way that use the table adapters with queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to use OleDB Commands:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record