# Using @@IDENTITY in a multi user environment

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The **SELECT @@IDENTITY** statement in Access VBA, would allow one to view/obtain the **AutoNumber** that has been generated in a table, for which a record has just been inserted, on the database. This is somewhat easy to track and maintain, if there is just one user and only one INSERT takes place at any moment of time.

My application is multi user, so far only one person used to do data entry. Now we have two people and when one user (Mr Brown) inserts a record (Auto ID : `1234`) and within a second (we are dealing with milliseconds) another (Mr Green) INSERTS a record (Auto ID : `1235`), the @@IDENTITY seems to return the latest ID `1235` for Mr. Brown and not 1234 which he inserted. As the same Mr. Green gets the same 1235, which is correct.

**My Question** is, is there a way to make sure that @@IDENTITY return the AutoID of that particular INSERT for that user that performed the INSERT. This is my code, if that helps.

```
tranDB As DAO.Database
Set tranDB = CurrentDb
tranSQL = "INSERT INTO Transactions (Password....." 'My Insert goes here

tranDB.Execute tranSQL

Dim idRS As DAO.Recordset
Set idRS = tranDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY AS LastID;")
TranID = idRS!LastID
idRS.Close
Set idRS = Nothing
```

**EDIT**: Not a Duplicate of [MS Access TableAdapter Get Identity after insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874526/ms-access-tableadapter-get-identity-after-insert). As the other thread involves with SQL Server, mine is JET Engine and Not .NET, I am using this code in VBA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS Access TableAdapter Get Identity after insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874526/ms-access-tableadapter-get-identity-after-insert)

Comment: @GSerg, I think SQL Server <> MS Access, .NET <> VBA

Comment: That question concerns MS Access. SQL Server is only mentioned in "All I found was for SQL Server." .NET is not relevant, what relevant is the technique - two commands executed under same connection.

Comment: @GSerg, So it is just a coincidence that the tags are just misleading in that? The answer posted has nothing to do with .NET or VB? The other post is `Retrieve the Identity Value While Inserting Records into Access Database By Using Visual Basic .NET` mine is `Retrieve the Identity Value While Inserting Records into Access Database By Using Visual Basic for Application`. The **technique** is using @@IDENTITY, my question concerns about multi user using the same backend, inserting into the same table at the same time. No offense, but I feel they are different in various level. Thanks !

Comment: Unsure it it's related to your issue, but if the tag is correct and this is Access 2010, you should be using ACE and not JET.

Comment: @GSerg, still think it is relevant? Or just do not wish to comment?

Comment: I never knew MS Access had `@@IDENTIY`. SQL Server does and in SQL Server you would use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get around your problem

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, you learn something new everyday. ;)

Comment: Is this application split, with each user having their own local copy of the front-end .accdb/.accde file?

Comment: @GordThompson, that is right ! Every user have their own copy of the front end with a backend that is linked to the tables in a network location.

Comment: I still think it is relevant and I do not wish to comment because you think otherwise, and I'm not in a position to force help on those who don't want it. The underlying principle remains the same - you must execute the two commands, the insert and the select, in the same batch in order to return the correct result. I do not know how to express that idea with DAO (the older thing that I don't use). I do know how to do it in ADO (the newer thing that I use) and I know Access supports ADO and references it by default, but you are using DAO, and it might be the case you'll have to switch to ADO.

Comment: I have been unable to recreate your issue so far. I created two separate front-ends with ACE DAO insert code very similar to yours in a loop to add 1000 rows (and then SELECT @@IDENTITY) as fast as they can. When I run the code simultaneously on both machines there is definitely contention on the back-end (since I had to trap errors 3045, 3073, 3704, and 3734) but when it's all over there are no cases of both machines receiving the same @@IDENTITY value. (I repeated the test a couple of times just to be sure.)

Comment: @GordThompson, Thank you for taking the effort to do a test case scenario. I have used this code for 3 years, working fine. Although there was only one Data insert I have similar code which is automated elsewhere and have never had issues, this is the first time I had this problem (as two people are on manual data entry). I will have a close eye to see if there is any other way I can trap this. Much appreciated !

Comment: Glad to help. Just for completeness: Your table doesn't happen to have an After Insert data macro that creates a record in some other table with an AutoNumber field, does it? That's the only scenario I've encountered (so far) where SELECT @@IDENTITY gets confused.

Answer (score 1):

Paul have your tried to encapsulate it within a transaction? try this

```
    Dim tranDB As DAO.Database
    Set tranDB = CurrentDb
    tranSQL = "INSERT INTO Transactions (Password....." 'My Insert goes here

    dbEngine.BeginTrans
    on Error goto ERROR_INSERT:
        tranDB.Execute tranSQL, dbFailOnError

        Dim idRS As DAO.Recordset
        Set idRS = tranDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY AS LastID;")
        'ideally put another error trap here
        TranID = nz(idRS("LastID"),0)
    DBEngine.CommitTrans

   On Error resume Next
   idRS.Close
   Set idRS = Nothing
   SET tranDB = nothing
   Exit sub/Function

ERROR_INSERT:
    dbengine.rollback
    'and  other stuffs or resume to exit label
```

Comment: Krish, the code does not throw an error. The problem is the @@IDENTITY giving the right ID for the wrong person. Mr Brown should get the ID for what he has inserted in the table (1234) and Mr Green should get the ID for what he has inserted (1235). Not Mr Brown and Mr Green both get 1235. If that makes sense. The above code, using an Error Trap does not make any difference IMVHO.

Comment: paul have you tried my code? i personally never tied @@identity i always use max(user_id) within a  transaction and it works everytime. the error trapping was just code improvement suggestion not directly anything to with your question :)

Comment: I have ***not*** tried your code (yet !). The @@IDENTITY, is a better method over Max(), as AutoNumber is not always sequential, sometime could set back to negatives - Although I have not personally got a negative autonumber, I personally known a few people who have come across negative AutoNumbers. So Max() would not get the -1236 (if that is what it get created), but 1235. However @@IDENTITY will give you -1236. I absolutely love the idea of using **BeginTrans** and **CommitTrans**. Cheers :)

Comment: maybe i used my way because i mostly use "unsigned" int ;) yes have nothing against your @@Identity approach. My suggestion was to use transactions/lockdown until you done with your operation. Everything else i've mentioned doesn't matter in terms of your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Paul,

I have used this technique for forever and it works for me (I would have lost my job many times over if it didn't work!!).

1) You have tagged this as an Access 10 question. So, are you using this reference in your project?:

```
Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEDAO.DLL
```

Older DAO references might be problematic. This feature is not supported before DAO 4.0.

2) Regarding krish's suggestion: transactions, while a good idea, are not required for this feature to work. The last Identity value is locally stored by the current connection. You just have have to call it before the user does another insert.

3) But, it is a good idea to use the same database reference to do both the Insert and retrieve the Identity. In your example, your use of tranDB *should* be correct -- but if you are re-assigning it to CurrentDB before calling Identity, this could be the problem.

4) Are you using Timestamps to be *sure* that Brown is inserting before Green?

5) As a last resort, you can try an all-DAO alternative:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' The query insert method is used here because DAO respects record-level locking
' on programmatically opened recordsets
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set idRs = tranDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, Password, InsertTime FROM Transactions (Password.....", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly + dbSeeChanges, dbOptimistic)
With idRs
    .AddNew
        !Password = sPassword
        !InsertTime = Now
    .Update
    ' Move to New Record
    .Bookmark = .LastModified
    lIdentity = !ID
    .Close
End With
```

See if this yields different results.