# Access create form to add data to nested m to n table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I got three tables `Orders` (1) &  `OrdersLinking` (2) &  `Products` (3).
1 and 3 have a m:n relation through 2 as linking table.

How would I make a form that can create a new entry in table 1 *and* 3. While there are no existing entrys in 2 due to the missing IDs (not created yet).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use autonumbers as your primary keys?

Comment: I'm actually not sure if that matters. I have the same set-up with a junction table and two data tables and adding to 1 and 3 first, then 2 works without problem. I lookup the PK's generated by my autonumbers using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628267/autonumber-value-of-last-inserted-row-ms-access-vba) and run all three appends using the same vba procedure. I've never had issues. If you go that route, [beware of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559408/using-identity-in-a-multi-user-environment)