How to insert multi valued field in a table using access vba
I'm writing a program by using MS Access VBA.
In this program I have textboxes that I fill them out and once I click on the button it inserts the values which are in the textboxes to a table named "Programs", but I have a lookup field that allows to select multi-values and I can't add the values into the Program table.
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute _
        "INSERT INTO Programs " & _
        "(Program_Name, Objectives, Targetted_Competency.[Value]) " & _
        "VALUES ('" & Me.txtProgramName & " ', '" & Me.txtObjectives & " ', '" & Me.txtTargettedCompetency & " ')"
    Programs_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub


Check these: How to insert multi valued field in a table using access vba , Update A multi-valued field in Access

A multi-value field requires special handling. Cannot update or insert simultaneous with other fields because a multi-value field is really sourced by a hidden dependent table. The field you see just stores pointers to records of hidden table. I NEVER NEVER use multi-value field.

This question is similar to: Update A multi-valued field in Access. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Why using VBA to insert data anyway? Why not just a bound form?

because I want the end user fill the textboxes and select from the multi-valued field and once he click on the button, I want the data to be inserted to "Programs" table. However I tried to apply the codes which is in the links (Update A multi-valued field in Access and How to insert multi valued field in a table using access vba), but it doesn't work

"Doesn't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Edit question to show attempted code. I would eliminate multi-value field and build a normal dependent table. In any case, will need to know ID of newly created primary record in order to then insert associated multi-value data. Explore @@IDENTITY https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559408/using-identity-in-a-multi-user-environment. Expect aggravation if you want to substitute Access GUI features with VBA.

If this is an UNBOUND form and users are selecting data destined for multi-value field, why set field as multi-value anyway? An UNBOUND form and UNBOUND textbox does not allow selection of multiple values. That can only be done with a combobox (or listbox also I think) BOUND to multi-value field.

I amended the code, but it displays error message "Type mismatch"

Read my first comment above.

It seems MsAccess keeps these multivalued field contents in DAO recordset format. You can not insert all of them using SQL (i.e. using the Currentdb.EXECUTE method); you will need to loop through the items in the combo/listbox, and insert one by one.
